# Sound file doesn't play when followed by exit(0) in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, avaudioplayer

OK, I want to have code that plays a certain sound file if the user quits, or if the user is eliminated from the game. After that, I want to exit the app.

So far, I have this:

```
@IBAction func justQuit(sender: UIButton)   // user just wants to quit game
{
      let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource
      ("PowerDown3",        ofType:"wav")
      let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

     do
     {
         let sdfx2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
         PowerDown3 = sdfx2
         sdfx2.play()
     } catch { /* couldn't load file */}

     exit(0)
}
```

I have the closing bracket to the above function, and have initialized the variables needed. I tried the code without the exit(0) command, and it plays the sound file, but when I include exit(0) to exit the app, the sound file does not play at all. The point is to exit the app, but before exiting, to play the 
sound file.

I even included a timer code to try to delay the exit(0) command, but still the sound file doesn't play. The timer didn't seem to make a difference to delay the exiting action.

Comment: Apps are not supposed to `exit` on iOS. Apple doesn't like it.

Comment: How *can* it play if the app exits? As Almo has mentioned, an app with exit in it won't be accepted in the app store.

Comment: perhaps I'll just do a segue back to the starting view instead, if Apple doesn't like "exit'.